# Running java application from cmd

Tags: java, cmd, project

I cannot open my Java App through CMD (Win 7)

This is where the Class is :

D:\Workspace\MessageQueingChat\src\model\Chat.java

I tried :

java -classpath D:\PBA Workspace\MessageQueingChat\src model.Chat topic username password

and many more cmd commands but it always returns :

Error: Could not find or load Main Class : Chat etc.

Any help will be appericiated.

Thanks.

EDIT : During compiling with javac it returns many errors and the first one is : package javax.jms does not exists.

Even though there are no problems in Eclipse with the import statment or anything..

Comment: Easily found on [google](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile with javac command and after you have to run .java file containing main class

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile your .java files into .classes? You should do it with javac before you can run those

Answer (score 0):

> the main method takes 3 parameters.

Thats invalid. Your Main Method should take a String-Array or no parameters.

```
class App {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      //do stuff
    }
}
```

With an invalid Method Signature, java can not find the entry point of yor application, therefore stating `class Main not found.`

See: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/anatomy/main.html

Answer (score 0):

your JAVA_HOME path is set? (JDK?)

then you have to compile it with:

javac D:\Workspace\MessageQueingChat\src\model\Chat.java

after compiling use

java D:\Workspace\MessageQueingChat\src\model\Chat

Answer (score 0):

First, compile the class files using javac or the Build button in your IDE.  Let's say you have compiled them to a folder called bin.  Then, cd to D:\Workspace\MessageQueingChat\bin and run "java model.Chat".  If you don't have the path to Java set as an environment variable, just include the full path to java like '"C:\Program Files\Java\Java 7\bin\java" model.Chat.'  The quotes are necessary if you have spaces in your directory names like "Program Files."

And as someone pointed out previously, if you have a main method that does not have the signature

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

then it will not recognize the main method so following the above instructions won't work until you have a correct main() method.

Comment: Thanks ! I do have the same method, altough in order for the program to work I have to pass three parameters ( topic,user,pass). Should I pass them during the compiling with javac or after when using java ?

Comment: You would pass them in when running "java" and your main class receives them as a three element array called args (the argument to the main() method).  So you might do something like "topic = args[0]; user = args[1]; pass = args[2]" inside main() (after you've checked that args.length >= 3 of course).